How to limit "admin rights" in GeoServer
Is it possible to create a user in GeoServer that can access all the pages in the Web Administration Interface, but can't change anything - i.e. create/update any configurations? The documentation states that:

Unless otherwise specified, you will need to be logged in with
administrative credentials to see the complete list of pages

Does that mean that I can create a user with read-only rights that can browse the entire interface? I can't find any further explanation in the GS documentation.

No, I (and I suspect the other maintainers) have never considered that as a use case. If you need this ability then you will need to contribute code or pay someone to contribute it for you.

Ok, thanks for the straight answer.
